# Additional fields and rows in FullCalendar V4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm using the latest V4 version of FullCalendar and I can't seem to be able to add additional fields like description and notes in my case.
I use the daygrid view and I would like two more fields to appear.

I've tried multiple options from answers here (probably for previous versions) and from the docs, including modifying the main.js from the core folder itself, where the titleHtml and timeHtml are defined (as (core.htmlEscape(eventDef.title)). 
I managed to add the fields or better said divs, which appear, but without content as eventDef.description is not a valid element, nor is evenDef.notes.

Where can I define these two into eventDef or how to append these fields and display them?

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var start = event.start; 
    var element = this;
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],
    defaultView: 'dayGridWeek',
    displayEventEnd:true,
    columnHeaderFormat:{ weekday: 'long', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', omitCommas: true }, 
    titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' },
    header: {center:  'title,prev,next', right:'', left:''},  
      eventTimeFormat: {
          hour: 'numeric',
          minute: '2-digit',
          meridiem: false
        },
      firstDay:1,
       events: [
        <?php get_data();?>
        ],
    });
    calendar.render(); 
  });

</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle of what you are trying?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Anyway you can add extra content to your events via the eventRender callback - check the docs. Have you tried it?

Comment: I did, but I don't want is as a tooltip, I want it to be displayed by default and I couldn't do that by using that callback, even by removing the tooltip part. Do you have any working examples, demos perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: In that callback, info.el is the HTML element representing the event as it will be displayed on the calendar. You can amend the contents of that element however you wish, using standard JavaScript. If I have time tomorrow and you're still stuck I can add a simple example.

Comment: I've added the fc-desc div as mentioned and then I used
`eventRender: function(info) {
              info.el.querySelector('.fc-desc').innerHTML = "" + info.event.description + "";
            }`
And it works, thanks Adyson!

Comment: No worries. BTW, you are allowed to answer your own question...since you solved it yourself, you should add the solution in the Answers section, below. That way a) it will show in search results for others with the same problem, and b) people can vote on it if they like it, which gets you points :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eventRender: function(info) { 
  info.el.querySelector('.fc-desc').innerHTML = "" + info.event.description + "";
}
```

This solved my problem, thanks to ADyson for help.

Comment: you know that the empty strings (`""`) are completely redundant here? They don't add any content to the HTML. It's not clear why you used them. `info.el.querySelector('.fc-desc').innerHTML = info.event.description;` will produce exactly the same result.