# JS change FullCalendar v4 event display

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

By using CSS I setup a default shape:

```
.fc-title {
    display:block;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

that displays each event in [blocks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-display).

What i need is to change some [events display](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-display).

For example : from start to the end of event will by going doted line with arrow at the end:

```
event start -----------------> event finish
```

Or just simple stripped line.

For this i try to use [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) but don't know how to setup another display option.

My attempt:

```
eventRender: function(info) {
    info.el.extendedProps('backgroundColor', 'red');
}
```

[Here](http://linkfor.com.br/assets/scss/core/plugins/_fullcalendar.scss) are some css examples for FullCalendar v3.

Note: I'm using v4

Comment: please show what you tried, exactly, using eventRender. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Question updated, unfortunately I don't know how can I access the corresponding option of the item 'event'

Comment: `eventRender: function(event, element) {` ...this syntax is from version 3. In v4 all the provided items, including the element (which will be a standard DOM element object, not a jQuery object), are contained within a single object passed into the callback. I would guess the code above will be giving you an error in your browser's Console. Always double-check a) the Console and b) the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender

Comment: @ADyson still i don't know how to change appearance of event element.

Comment: info.el doesn't have an extendedProps property. `info.el` is a HTML element, not a fullCalendar event object (that's inside `info.event`). You can change the contents of the HTML element using any standard Javascript which you would normally use to manipulate a HTML element (e.g. if you want to set its CSS then use the `style` property). Someone asked something quite similar yesterday, there is an answer attached: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592548/additional-fields-and-rows-in-fullcalendar-v4

Comment: Or here's a super-simple example of changing the background colour: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/vYYeryJ

Comment: @ADyson ok all fine, but how to access variable that changes the displayed shape of event?

Comment: The HTML element used to show the event is a `<div>`. In the callback, that div is represented by the `info.el` variable. You can use CSS styles to change its appearance, within the limits of what's possible using CSS. And you can use JavaScript to alter the contents of the div. e.g. you could remove borders and background so it just appears as text, or you could remove the text and change the height, or whatever you like. From your question, beyond adding an arrow to the text, it's not really clear what exact outcome you want.

Comment: @Adyson ok, with ---> i mean to change div shape to dotted

Comment: You mean something like this: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/vYYeryJ ? I don't know really what you mean by having the "shape" as dotted. A dotted line isn't a shape...it's just a line. Have you got an example of what you mean which you could show me? Or you could draw a mock-up?

Comment: @ADyson thank You for suggestions, now i understand how to get into div options :). By arrow i mean to change div background that will display only arrow ---> instead of any color from start date to end date for selected event